# cassandra bind variables produces error: no viable alternative at input '?'

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-c++-driver

I'm using cassandra. I am trying to update the `gc_grace` value using new bind variable.

```
ALTER table  keyspace.table_name with gc_grace_seconds = ? ;
```

I got the following error:

> no viable alternative at input '?'

How can I solve this?

Comment: why do you need binding here? From where do you fire this query? from cqlsh?

Comment: @Alex Ott 
no from c code.
using DataStax C/C++ Driver

Answer (score 2):

As I see from the source code (maybe I'm wrong), but `ALTER TABLE` doesn't support bindings, so you can't use them for this command (and all DDL commands), and need to just use `execute` with specific value

Comment: yes. i checked and i did not find any documentation mentioned that the Alter support binding, while insert and select support binding variables.
Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to bind parameters programatically to set GC grace on a table. It isn't possible to do that using the Cassandra drivers.

It will only work through cqlsh. For example:

```
cqlsh> ALTER TABLE community.maptbl WITH gc_grace_seconds = 3600;
```

It doesn't make sense to do it in your app and it is not recommended. Cheers!